# How to describe the size of this garden faucet fixture?

Tags: faucet

I could use some help understanding how to measure and describe the size of a garden faucet.

I need to replace a garden faucet fixture (for the sorry details, see [How to repair this leaking garden faucet - update (broken stem)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/193363/how-to-repair-this-leaking-garden-faucet-update-broken-stem)).

I measured the two openings but the measurements do not agree with the stamp on the side.  The stamp says 1/2. The inner diameter of the two openings are 3/4 and 5/8. (See photos.)

What size fixture should I buy to replace the broken one?

(I am not going out to shop due to the pandemic. I seek enough information to order a replacement online.)

Thank you.
[image: 1/2 stamped on side]
[image: 3/4 ID]
[image: 5/8 ID]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bog-standard **boiler drain valve.** 1/2" Male Pipe Threads (which are larger than 1/2", as 1/2" is the size of the hole in the pipe) on the inlet and Garden Hose Threads on the outlet.

You can also get a "frost free hose bibb" also called a sillcock which has a much longer body so that the actual valve and male pipe thread is inside the building while the hose thread and handle are on the outside of the building, but that would presumably require changing the pipes it's connected to.

Comment: Take the valve to a plumbing supply or big box and get a new one with the same size and threads.

Comment: @JimStewart  I am not going out to shop due to the pandemic.  I seek enough information to order a replacement online.